# Laravel images, js and files are returning a 404 (deprecated)

Tags: laravel

NOT NEEDED ANYMORE

old question: This is how the images are called:

```
<img src="/images/layout/incassomachtigen.png" />
```

The public folder is in the root so maybe that has to do with it?

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Also, some of the images have 2 slashes in the network tab:

```
http://localhost:8000/images//layout/intentie.jpg
```

Comment: How are you running your website? Are you using apache? or are you running `php artisan serve`?

Comment: @aceraven777 php artisan serve

Comment: And your image in inside `public/images/layout/incassomachtigen.png`?

Answer (score -1):

Your internal links to images, css and js should be like this pattern. Change it related to your Laravel path.

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/layout/incassomachtigen.png') }}" class="" alt="">
```

Comment: Why should they "_be like this pattern_"? What does `{{ asset() }}` do?

Comment: @brombeer There is a golden phrase in eastern ancient countries like Iran, China and Egypt. "Never discuss about wise things with a silly". Don't blab in the future.

Answer (score -1):

use the following way. Hope this solves your problem

```
<img src="{{asset('/images/layout/incassomachtigen.png')}}" />
```

Comment: Not possible due to it already being an existing project. I have cloned it and i'm trying to setup a dev environment

Comment: What would that change? `{{asset()}}` is only really useful if you have `ASSET_URL` set to an external url